# is there a faster method to calculate $1/x$ ($x$ an integer) than this?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, numerical-methods, fractions, recursive-algorithms

I gave this stackexchange a second go. Is there a faster way to calculate $1/x$ than the following:

1. Calculate $100/x$ (.or other arbitrary positive power of $10$) with remainder
2. Write multiplier in hundredths 
   place.
3. Calculate remainder$/x$ as 
   multiplier times remainder but 
   shifted over to where decimal 
   point is at where you are in $1/x$
4. repeat step 3, taking your new 
   decimal expansion as the new 
   multiplier (without the $0$ before 
   the decimal point) and square 
   your previous remainder.

ex. $1/97 =$

1. $97$ goes $1$ time remainder $3$.
2. $0.01$
3. $0.0103$
4. $0.0103+0.00000927$
5. $0.01030927+0.0000000083505087$
   ...

5 steps in, we Already have $13$ correct digits. Via group theory it has to have a length that's a divisor of $96$ $(1,2,3,4,6,8,12,16,24,32,48,$ or $96)$ so we've eliminated $7$ of $12$ possible lengths.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate $1/x$ as your text says or the number of digits in the repeat of $1/x$ as the final line implies?

Comment: 1/x but with knowledge you can calculate reptend length to know when you can stop.

Comment: You know when to stop when the remainder is $1$ because you are back where yo started.  I don't have an easier way than long division to get $1/x$

Comment: this method only uses 1 division the rest is squaring, multiplying, shifting and adding. It's based on squaring a number squares it's remainder.

Comment: Also where you hit 1 remainder will depend on how you do the division by an arbitrary power of 10. That's partly why the group theory becomes useful.

Comment: In this context, "fast" is undefined. Because you don't specify the cost of the operations, e.g. "$97$ goes $1$ time remainder $3$". This is not for free.

Comment: I know computers are slow at dividing compared with multiplication and addition.

Comment: It is still unclear what you're asking.  You are asking about some class of problems, illustrated by division by $97$.  If you intend computation strictly with integers, starting with $x$ an integer, then likely you have in mind a precise form of the output required as the integer form(?) of the repeating part of the rational decimal expansion.  However there can be a "leading part" the decimal expansion not included in the repeating part.

Answer (score 5):

Newton's method for $\frac{1}{A}$ is to iterate 
$$  x \; \; \; \mapsto \; \; \; \; 2x-A x^2 = x (2-Ax)  $$

```
parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500000
? a = 97
%1 = 97
? 
? x = 0.01
%4 = 0.01000000000000000000000000000
? 
? x = x * ( 2 - a * x )
%5 = 0.01030000000000000000000000000
? 
? x = x * ( 2 - a * x )
%6 = 0.01030927000000000000000000000
? 
? x = x * ( 2 - a * x )
%7 = 0.01030927835050870000000000000
? 
? x = x * ( 2 - a * x )
%8 = 0.01030927835051546391752576876
? 
? x = x * ( 2 - a * x )
%9 = 0.01030927835051546391752577320
?
```

Comment: And this is faster ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee it might be the same method. You should check that. Meanwhile, Newton's method has quadratic convergence, the number of correct decimal paces roughly doubles at each step.

Comment: same with this one.

Comment: A note on the question: this is about computer arithmetic, because division is always the slow operation.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how many digits precision you want. If you calculate 100/x with an integer x with straightforward long division, the digits will repeat with a period of (x-1). So if the number of digits you want is n >> x, you just calculate the first x-1 digits, and then you repeat them until you have n digits. This runs in O (n), with a small constant factor once you have got the first x digits, which is easily done in c * (x log x) operations.