# Approximate square root or logarithm with addition, subtraction, multiplication and division

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, arithmetic, continued-fractions

In some data science applications, one would like to normalize a count number with the square root, the logarithm, log(x+1) or a related subadditive function.

In the SPARQL 1.1 language, only addition, subtraction, multiplication and division exist. I would like to construct a subadditive or logarithm-like function SPARQL.

Is it possible to construct a finite non-iterative  (x>a)-subadditive function, e.g., an approximate square root function, with only addition, subtraction, multiplication and division that works across a "reasonable" range of non-negative integers?

My current best bet is some form of finite continued fraction on log(x+1). However, the test that I made on one form showed it to be "insufficiently" subadditive, i.e., just a linear asymptote.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2612491) there is a square root algorithm based on addictions and subtractions only.

Comment: You can use the Heron method, if you do not demand great efficiency.

Comment: As far as I can determine the the Heron method is somewhat dependent on the initial guess, - at least when there are few terms (such as 3 that I tried).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3116326/is-there-a-faster-method-to-calculate-1-x-x-an-integer-than-this