# $2^n$th decimal place of $\sqrt{2}.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, radicals, decimal-expansion

Someone on Art of Problem Solving claims to know how to calculate the $2^{2020}$th decimal place of $\sqrt{2},$ and will tell us if everyone gives up. Brute force will not work, nor will a BBP style formula (for the reason that one does not exist, and the ones known so far are for base $2^k$ expansions; $10$ is not a power of $2$).

Is there a feasible solution, or am I being trolled? Trying to search various queries relating to my question online results in nothing except spigot algorithms which spit out the digits one by one from the start. As you may know, they will not work. I am operating under the assumption that if a clever solution exists, it is not a new discovery, for such a simple question has surely been considered before.

Update: The problem poster has promised to post the solution in 2021 if no one finds it before then. This is not the first time they've done this, but every time they've done this in previous years, they have delivered on the promises.

2nd Update: 2 weeks left and I've forgotten to show the [source](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1991934p13884856). Soon we'll see if we have been trolled or not.

Comment: My suspicion is you are likely being trolled. Such an algorithm will likely be publish-worthy.

Comment: you only need to know $2^{n+1}$ digits of an eighth root  to find the $2^{n+3}$ th digit of the sqrt.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Good idea, but how do you find the $8$th root?

Comment: I'll admit not easily but you could use a similar trick to what I started with that would allow you to calculate more digits of it. which means higher precision in your square root answer after cubing.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee By "similar trick to what I started with", do you mean taking the square root of $2 \cdot 10^{2^{2021}}$? That's unfeasible.

Comment: no but you can apply the same trick to a smaller region and work up to it. newtons method is quadratic in nature for approximations. 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3116326/is-there-a-faster-method-to-calculate-1-x-x-an-integer-than-this  for example is close to this.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee What smaller region? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: know the first 16 you can predict the 32nd. etc. for 8th roots to sqrt you can use 16 to predict 48 of the sqrt or more.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee But then you need to know the first $2^{2019}$ digits, which is still unfeasible. How would you even store them?

Comment: The iteration $x_0=1$, $x_{n+1}=\dfrac12(x_n+2/x_n)$ does (roughly) double the number of correct decimals in each iteration, but this won't let you calculate an individual decimal far out. And as pointed out by many, calculating all of them up to that point is a non-starter.

Comment: We have

$$
\sqrt2=\frac12\left(3-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^n\frac1{a_k}\right)
$$

with $a_1=6$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n^2-2$. The number of digits in the denominator grows exponentially, so you only need to include about $2000$ terms to get the $2^{2020}$-th digit right. That leaves the problem of how to extract the relevant digits of each term. I don&rsquo;t know a feasible way to do that. The decimal periods seem to be relatively short (e.g. the third term, $\frac1{235416}$, has decimal period $576$), but I doubt they&rsquo;re short enough.

Comment: (For more on this series, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Series_and_product_representations) and OEIS sequences [A082405](https://oeis.org/A082405), [A001109](https://oeis.org/A001109) and [A228931](https://oeis.org/A228931).)

Comment: @Mourad: The terms in that series only decrease as $10^{-8k}$; that's not nearly enough to make it feasible to obtain the $2^{2020}$-th digit – you'd have to sum something like $2^{2000}$ terms. I don't see from what you conclude that the series I suggested can only provide $1$ or $2$ decimal places.

Comment: @Aryabhata Perhaps this person is the victim of a fallacy.

Comment: @joriki Good luck to calculate the $2000$ th term of this sequence.

Comment: @Displayname The formula you mentioned ($\pi$ in base $2$) would also be useless to calculate the $2^{2020}$-th digit. This formula does not allow to calculate then $n$-th bit of $\pi$ "immediately", it only can do it without calculating all the previous digits.

Comment: I wonder if one can say anything about the number whose $n$-th digit is the $2^n$-th digit of $\sqrt{2}$. Probably not.

Comment: @Displayname "they have delivered on the promises" ? Maybe, but this time it seems to be a hoax, but the reactions to this question shows that such hoaxes are successful. Seriousness does not matter, the main point is to mention something "interesting". Religion in mathematics !

Comment: If there is a solution given in 2021, kindly copy (or link to) it here.

Comment: @Peter. Look up BBP style formulas which do allow extracting a digit without computing earlier digits. The famous case is $\pi$ in base 16 (hence base 2 too).

Comment: @Displayname, If we take log, we get $0.5 log 2=log a-log(10^n) $, where a is the number its (n+1)th is what you want. $a=10^n\times10^{0.5 log 2}$. $10^{0.5log 2}=1.1414213562 $ which is the value of $\sqrt 2$. So this is like asking to find the nth decimal digit of $10^{0.5 log 2}$ which seems to be simpler to find.

Comment: To motivate people that this isn't a hoax it would be good to include a link to the AOPS source and perhaps some examples of "promises they've delivered on".

Comment: Why don't we see the statistical distribution of the digits of $√2$. That may give some insight.

Comment: Things I found: a) If the denominator $m$ has at most a few million digits, it is possible to calculate the $2^{2020}$-th digit of $1/m$ using for example pari/gp. This is done  by repeatedly squaring $10$ modulo $10m$... In this way, one can treat the first 20 terms of joriki's series. b) There are rational approximations of $\sqrt2$ only containing powers of 2 in the denominator 
(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#A_two-variable_iterative_method))
Problem: What to do if the denominator cannot be represented in the computer?

Comment: I notice the original author of the question has posted a similar puzzle [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u368751h1993781p19751717) without answering the first one. This makes me suspect they don't have an answer.

Comment: @OscarCunningham The thread was [locked](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1991934p13884856) after the author refused to share their work. I'm disappointed by the outcome, but in hindsight, something was likely to go wrong with such a difficult and seemingly impossible problem.

Answer (score 1):

Required digits equals to $d_n=\bar d(2^n),\;$ where
$$\bar d(k)=\left\lfloor 10^{k}\sqrt 2\right\rfloor\hspace{-10pt}\mod 10,\tag1$$
$$\{d_n\}=\{{1, 2, 6, 0, 9, 9, 5, 3, 6, 5, 9, 4, 7, 4, 0, 9, 4, 9, 0, 6, \dots}\}$$

Alternative way is to use the expression
$$d_n=\left\lfloor 10^{2^n}a(n)\right\rfloor\hspace{-10pt}\mod 10,\quad n=1,2\dots\tag2$$
where $a(n)$ can be defined via [recurrence relation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%280%29%3D3%2F2%2C%20a%28k%2B1%29%3Da%28k%29%2F2%2B1%2Fa%28k%29%20)
$$a(0)=\dfrac32,\quad a(n+1)=\frac12a(n)+a(n)^{-1},\tag3$$
or from the closed form
$$a(n)=\sqrt2\coth\left(2^{n}\ln\left(3+2\sqrt2\right)\right),\quad n=1,2,\dots\tag4$$
Formulas $(2),(3)$ allow to operate with the rational numbers. This provides exact result.

**EDIT of 30.07.23**

At the same time, is possible improved algorithm in the form of
$$\begin{align}
&d_n=b_n\hspace{-8pt} \mod 10,\quad n=0, 1, 2\dots,\\[4pt]
&b_0=14,\quad b_{n+1} = \dfrac12 10^{2^n}\, b_n+\genfrac\lfloor\rfloor{}{}{1000^{2^n}}{b_n},
\end{align}\tag5$$
which stores the intermediate results in the integer format.

Comment: $(3)$ is fast but we can't afford to store all of the digits in the process.

Comment: @Displayname Thanks! Improved.

Comment: There is not enough room in the universe to store $b_{1000}$ as an integer.

Comment: @Displayname Some megabytes, really. And a package of extended mathematics)

Comment: $1000^{2^n}$ has $3 \cdot 2^n$ digits, how do we do the division quickly? We can't save time factoring out the powers of $10$ because there will be almost nothing to factor as seen by computing $b_1, b_2, b_3.$